# Devede not installable 22.04 LTS

Tags: dependencies, vlc, ffmpeg

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS had Devede installed and worked fine. Updated to 22.04 LTS and this, and other programs (e.g. Audacious) disappeared, either immediately, or subsequently. Cannot re-install. Tried manually with Devede, get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install devede
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 devede : Depends: ffmpeg or
                   mencoder but it is not installable
          Depends: mpv but it is not installable or
                   vlc but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

n.b. VLC is installed, and works.

I haven't a clue what this means.

ps ffmpeg won't install either, and a similar message appears. The GUI installation through Ubuntu or Gnome doesn't work, either, and provides no information at all.

Comment: "*I haven't a clue what this means.*" It means that your problem is self-inflicted. You installed some non-Ubuntu package(s) that are incompatible with all those applications. You fix your system by removing the incompatible package(s).

Comment: But I haven't installed any non-Ubuntu packages, at least not knowingly. As I said, a range of applications was deleted by the upgrade process from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. They quite happily worked before, but simply disappeared from the favourites icons bordering the home screen during the process, and, although they can be relocated in Ubuntu sources, cannot be re-installed. The only thing that does not come from a specifically Ubuntu source is get_iplayer, which works well, still, and was not affected by the upgrade process. I use that a lot.

Comment: The reference to the other question helped, in that an answer suggested using aptitude.to install another package which produced a similar outcome to my attempts with devede. I tried this, and after three failed attempts, it produced a solution on the fourth which I let it proceed with. It worked. I had never heard of aptitude and had to install it first, though. The process also installed ffmpeg, which was another thing that disappeared when I upgraded to 22.04lts and I couldn't get back. Audacious still won't install, but I'll try aptitude with that in due course.

Comment: "*a range of applications was deleted by the upgrade process from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS*" That means your release-upgrade was incomplete or blocked by wrong-version or non-Ubuntu packages. Again, almost always self-inflicted. Since you do not recall how you inflicted those wrong-version or non-Ubuntu packages upon your system, you have two choices: You can learn the skills to identify them or you can simply reinstall Ubuntu. Your Aptitude solution may work for a while, but it's unlikely to be a permanent repair.

Comment: So, at some time prior to mid-2022 I “inflicted” a package on Ubuntu that is causing this problem. This is an unduly puritan attitude. Whatever it was that was installed, it was done because Ubuntu did not provide me with an application I needed at the time, possibly still do, so I got what I needed somewhere else. I refuse to pretend a sense of shame or repentance for this. As for learning new skills, I don't mind that, but the process had better be quick and easy since I'm 70 in a few days. I don't have much time, and none available to be preached at! Botched repairs are probably sufficient.

Comment: "*I refuse to pretend a sense of shame or repentance for this.*" Not intended, and apologies. The term "self-inflicted" simply means that it's not a software bug. A human order created the problem. Your options remain.